# Detect text and deskew

Tags: python, opencv

Similar questions have been asked, but none of them seem to help in my case (nevertheless, I learned a few things from those threads).

[image: A sample picture]

I am using Tesseract for OCR, but the results are far from satisfactory when the text is slightly skewed (see the image above).

Inspired by similar cases, I tried to use OpenCV to detect and fix the skew, but unfortunately it just doesn't seem to work. Below, you can see my current attempt, which doesn't yield the necessary result. What I get is just another bounding box around the image (that has already been cropped).

```
import cv2
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
img = cv2.imread("skew.JPG")
gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)  
#gray = cv2.bitwise_not(gray)
ret,thresh1 = cv2.threshold(gray, 0, 255 ,cv2.THRESH_OTSU)     
rect_kernel = cv2.getStructuringElement(cv2.MORPH_ELLIPSE, (3
, 2))
dilation = cv2.dilate(thresh1, rect_kernel, iterations = 1)
cv2.imshow('dilation', dilation)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(dilation, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)
for cnt in contours:
        rect = cv2.minAreaRect(cnt)
        box = cv2.boxPoints(rect)
        box = np.int0(box)
        cv2.drawContours(img,[box],0,(0,0,255),3)
cv2.imshow('final', img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

I would appreciate any advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tesseract seems to have a lot of troubles when the text has some distortions.

The idea is to find the contour of the text to be able to undistort the image and then use Tesseract. 
The contour is generally a rectangle which has undergone the same distortion as the text. So it does not appear as a perfect rectangle in your image anymore. Opencv gives you different methods to find it. `cv2.minAreaRect()` finds the best rotated rectangle. It may be sufficient depending on the distortion of your text. Otherwise, you can use `cv2.convexHull()` to better fit your text.

The contour should give you the corners of the text that you want to remap to a regular rectangle. You can do that with:

```
cv2.getAffineTransform(corners, dest_corners)    # requires 3 points
cv2.getPerspectiveTransform(corners, dest_corners)    # requires 4 points
```

and then

```
 cv2.warpAffine(...)
 cv2.warpPerspective(...)
```

Also, don't forget to correctly set the page segmentation method that Tesseract needs to use (https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality). In your case, "6    Assume a single uniform block of text." seems to be adapted.

Comment: Thank you very for your response. I still have very little experience with OpenCV, so can you please confirm whether my summary of your answer is accurate:

1)  I can still use cv2.minAreaRect like I did above, but depending on the result I might need to use cv2.convexHull()

2) After that, I should use `cv2.getAffineTransform(...) -> cv2.warpAffine()` (or the second option with perspective). 


What about the preprocessing? Is what I posted above adequate?

Comment: Yes, you can start with cv2.minAreaRect. It will fit the best rectangle around your text. So, if your text has only been rotated, this should be sufficient. But if your text has undergone perspective deformation, a rotated rectangle will not fit the text correctly. In that case you can use a convex hull, but it will also requires a bit of additional work to find the 4 good corners of the text from the hull.

Comment: I am currently using minAreaRect and for some reason it just draws a bounding box that I already have after the object detection stage (the images were cropped). Maybe, I am just not using it properly.

Comment: Did you check the points that you passed to minAreaRect? The function will find minimum-area bounding rectangle. You should pass only the points that correspond to the letters. (maybe using a threshold on the color)